# WPF Select ComboBox text style based on variable

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `ComboBox` and I'd like to be able to change the style of the text inside the `ComboBoxItem` based on an attribute of the `ComboBoxItem`.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Focusable="False">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I've been trying to set the TextBlock Style from `MyStyle` to a different one if the Country's attribute `IsWestern` is true, but I am not managing. I figure I need a `Trigger` somewhere, but I can't figure it out and added a variety, but none worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use DataTrigger to change ContentTemplate:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsWestern}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource WesternStyle}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

alternatively include `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsWestern}" Value="True">` in TextBlock Style (MyStyle) and change required TextBlock properties there:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="BlockLineHeight"></Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsWestern}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,0,0,0"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

Comment: Hey @ASh, thanks for your response! I tried your code, but unfortunately this overwrites all the other styles that are after the textblock (there are a few more things in the `<Setter.Value>` that I omitted for simplicity. For your second solution, you mean to change the stylesheet somehow?

Comment: I don't understand what overrides what? It is hard to advise without seeing [mcve]

Comment: Hey ASh, I was able to do this with your second suggestion! I'll update your answer :)